# How to check compatibility of an css file?

Tags: css

I am looking for an easy way to check, if a given css file uses features that are not compatible with a certain browser.

Something like a combination of the W3C CSS validator and the database of caniuse.com.

Any suggestions?

Comment: Do you mean something such as modernizr?

Comment: Should it be usable in your Javascript (then modernizr is good) or are you just looking for a tool you can throw your CSS into and get a report from it?

Comment: The latter: Just a online or offline tool to get a report.

Answer (score 0):

If looking for an tool to report them,

I use Sublime Text with a plugin called "SublimeLinter-csslint". it gives yellow box around the code (warning) and the description below.

I am not sure it checks all but it does pretty good job. Specially with EI capabilities.

Also i just found this plugin https://packagecontrol.io/packages/W3CValidators ( im not using it, but i think it'll work too )